# Apply a list of functions to a corresponding list of data in Clojure

Tags: clojure

So I have a list of functions and a list of data:

```
[fn1 fn2 fn3] [item1 item2 item3]
```

What can I do to apply each function to its corresponding data item:

```
[(fn1 item1) (fn2 item2) (fn3 item3)]
```

Example:

```
[str #(* 2 %) (partial inc)]   [3 5 8]

=> ["3" 10 9]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `map`

```
(map #(%1 %2) [str #(* 2 %) (partial inc)] [3 5 8])
("3" 10 9)
```

If you need a vector back, you can `(apply vector ...)`

```
(apply vector (map #(%1 %2) [str #(* 2 %) (partial inc)] [3 5 8]))
["3" 10 9]
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't know much Clojure, so there would probably be better ways to do this.</sub>

Comment: Nice! Thanks! It seems like `(partial inc)` doesn't work but `(partial + 1)` does!

Comment: @user1184248 I'd think `(partial inc)` would work, but it is the same as just `inc`.

Comment: For getting back a vector, a little shorter: `(mapv #(%1 %2) [str #(* 2 %) inc] [3 5 8])`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, not necessarily better:

```
user=> (for [[f x] (map vector [neg? pos? number?] [1 2 "foo"])]
  #_=>   (f x))
(false true false)
```

To make the `map` version suitable for varargs:

```
user=> (map (fn [f & args] (apply f args)) [+ - *] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
(12 -11 162)
```